# AngularJs Unknown provider error when using angular.bootstrap()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code:

```
myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$controllerProvider', 
                       '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider',  
                       'routeResolver', myConfigFunction] );
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

Whenever I do this, I get the error: `Unknown provider: routeResolver from myApp`

If however I move the `angular.bootstrap` before the config function, ie:

```
myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);    

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$controllerProvider', 
                       '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider',  
                       'routeResolver', myConfigFunction] );
```

Then I don't get any errors, but the config function `myConfigFunction` is not called. (The function just logs a line to console).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you use Chrome or IE?

Comment: @MaximShoustin Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what `routeResolver` actually is (might be [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/05/22/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs.aspx)?)

Since only providers can be injected into the `config()` block you also need to add the word `provider` so `routeResolver` becomes `routeResolverProvider` and the error will go away.

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$controllerProvider', 
                       '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider',  
                       'routeResolverProvider', myConfigFunction] );
```

[**Working example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Pn2Xn/)

Comment: `Since only providers can be injected into the config() block` this should be mentioned in the documentation somewhere...but thanks. Is this only the config block, or is it the same everywhere i.e in order for the dependency block to work, all services must have providers?

Comment: and you are correct, routeResolve is inspired by what that article said. :)

Comment: It is mentioned under the config section in the module documentation. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: Not all services require providers, you can use providers when you want to make your service configurable.

Comment: This is still not working, I get the same error. Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/rMHME/

Comment: I can see that you're using a separate module for your service whereas I'm using the same `myApp` one, could that be why?

Comment: You need to have `Provider` added to the name, see updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/rMHME/2/

Comment: I could kiss you. In fact, I could actually make out with you.